# looping through multiple of the same nodes in an xml bill and merging a list that has 2 string values

Tags: c#, xml, c#-4.0, xml-parsing

I am having an issue where I am looping through multiple of the same nodes in an xml bill. I am looping through the values and merging them accordingly. I'm having an issue merging a charge list that contains two string values (Name and Amount). I need to keep the name the same and just sum/merge the amount values together. The loop contains all of the values included in the node but I am only showing the portion I need help with.

This is what it looks like before I tried to merge it together. I also added a little snippet of the xml for just the charge portion

```
private static ServiceAddressBillDetail GetServiceAccountUsageAndBillingDetail(string requestSA, string xmlBill, XmlNodeList detailPageNodes)
{
    var saBillDetail = new ServiceAddressBillDetail();
    saBillDetail.UsageServiceName = requestSA;

    foreach (XmlNode detailPageNode in detailPageNodes)
    {

        if (saBillDetail.Charges == null)
        {
            saBillDetail.Charges = new List<Charge>();
        }
        saBillDetail.Charges = XmlBillParser.GetChargeList(detailPageNode);     
    }
} 

public static List<Charge> GetChargeList(XmlNode detailPageNode)
{
    var chargeList = new List<Charge>();

    PullChargesFromXml("IRBILGS_CD_COM_OR_FINAR_DESC.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CHARGES_DETAIL", "IRBILGS_CD_AMT.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CHARGES_DETAIL", false, detailPageNode.SelectNodes("Elec_Dtl_b"), chargeList);
    PullChargesFromXml("Cost of electricity you used", "IRBILGR_CG_TOT_AMT.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CHARGES_HEADER", true, detailPageNode.SelectNodes("Elec_Total_Bold_Underline"), chargeList);
    PullChargesFromXml("IRBILGS_CD_COM_OR_FINAR_DESC.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CHARGES_DETAIL", "IRBILGS_CD_AMT.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CHARGES_DETAIL", false, detailPageNode.SelectNodes("Taxes_Dtl"), chargeList);
    PullChargesFromXml("Cost of electricity with taxes and fees", "IRBILGP_SA_TOT_ELEC_CHRG.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_STATEMENT", true, detailPageNode.SelectNodes("Taxes_Total_Bold_Underline"), chargeList);

    var node = detailPageNode.SelectNodes("OtherCharges_Dtl");
    if (node.Count > 0)
    {
        chargeList.AddRange(node.Cast<XmlNode>().Select(p => new Charge
        {
            Name = p.SelectSingleNode("IRBILGS_CD_COM_OR_FINAR_DESC.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CHARGES_DETAIL").InnerText + " " +
                   p.SelectSingleNode("IRBILGS_CD_TRAN_DT.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CHARGES_DETAIL").InnerText,
            Amount = p.SelectSingleNode("IRBILGS_CD_AMT.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CHARGES_DETAIL").InnerText
        }).ToList());
    }

    node = detailPageNode.SelectNodes("GenElec_Dtl");
    if (node.Count > 0)
    {
        PullChargesFromXml("IRBILGS_CD_COM_OR_FINAR_DESC.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CHARGES_DETAIL", "IRBILGS_CD_AMT.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CHARGES_DETAIL", false, detailPageNode.SelectNodes("GenElec_Dtl"), chargeList);
        PullChargesFromXml("Total electricity you sold", "IRBILGR_CG_TOT_AMT.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CHARGES_HEADER", true, detailPageNode.SelectNodes("GenElec_Total_Bold_Underline"), chargeList);
    }

    PullChargesFromXml("Total charges for electricity services", "IRBILGP_SA_TOT_CHRG.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_STATEMENT", true, detailPageNode.SelectNodes("Svc_Total_Bold"), chargeList);

    return chargeList;
}

<Elec_Dtl_b>
  <IRBILGS_CD_COM_OR_FINAR_DESC.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CHARGES_DETAIL>Customer account charge</IRBILGS_CD_COM_OR_FINAR_DESC.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CHARGES_DETAIL>
  <IRBILGS_CD_AMT.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CHARGES_DETAIL>$1.95</IRBILGS_CD_AMT.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CHARGES_DETAIL>
</Elec_Dtl_b>
<Elec_Dtl_b>
  <IRBILGS_CD_COM_OR_FINAR_DESC.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CHARGES_DETAIL>Delivery service charge</IRBILGS_CD_COM_OR_FINAR_DESC.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CHARGES_DETAIL>
  <IRBILGS_CD_AMT.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CHARGES_DETAIL>$8.34</IRBILGS_CD_AMT.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CHARGES_DETAIL>
</Elec_Dtl_b>
<Elec_Dtl_b>
  <IRBILGS_CD_COM_OR_FINAR_DESC.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CHARGES_DETAIL>Environmental benefits surcharge</IRBILGS_CD_COM_OR_FINAR_DESC.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CHARGES_DETAIL>
  <IRBILGS_CD_AMT.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CHARGES_DETAIL>$3.99</IRBILGS_CD_AMT.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CHARGES_DETAIL>
</Elec_Dtl_b>
<Elec_Dtl_b>
  <IRBILGS_CD_COM_OR_FINAR_DESC.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CHARGES_DETAIL>Federal environmental improvement surcharge</IRBILGS_CD_COM_OR_FINAR_DESC.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CHARGES_DETAIL>
  <IRBILGS_CD_AMT.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CHARGES_DETAIL>$0.01</IRBILGS_CD_AMT.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CHARGES_DETAIL>
</Elec_Dtl_b>
<Elec_Dtl_b>
  <IRBILGS_CD_COM_OR_FINAR_DESC.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CHARGES_DETAIL>System benefits charge</IRBILGS_CD_COM_OR_FINAR_DESC.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CHARGES_DETAIL>
  <IRBILGS_CD_AMT.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CHARGES_DETAIL>$0.92</IRBILGS_CD_AMT.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CHARGES_DETAIL>
</Elec_Dtl_b>
<Elec_Dtl_b>
  <IRBILGS_CD_COM_OR_FINAR_DESC.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CHARGES_DETAIL>Power supply adjustment*</IRBILGS_CD_COM_OR_FINAR_DESC.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CHARGES_DETAIL>
  <IRBILGS_CD_AMT.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CHARGES_DETAIL>$0.27</IRBILGS_CD_AMT.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CHARGES_DETAIL>
</Elec_Dtl_b>
<Elec_Dtl_b>
  <IRBILGS_CD_COM_OR_FINAR_DESC.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CHARGES_DETAIL>Metering*</IRBILGS_CD_COM_OR_FINAR_DESC.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CHARGES_DETAIL>
  <IRBILGS_CD_AMT.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CHARGES_DETAIL>$2.79</IRBILGS_CD_AMT.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CHARGES_DETAIL>
</Elec_Dtl_b>
<Elec_Dtl_b>
  <IRBILGS_CD_COM_OR_FINAR_DESC.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CHARGES_DETAIL>Meter reading*</IRBILGS_CD_COM_OR_FINAR_DESC.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CHARGES_DETAIL>
  <IRBILGS_CD_AMT.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CHARGES_DETAIL>$1.92</IRBILGS_CD_AMT.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CHARGES_DETAIL>
</Elec_Dtl_b>
<Elec_Dtl_b>
  <IRBILGS_CD_COM_OR_FINAR_DESC.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CHARGES_DETAIL>Billing*</IRBILGS_CD_COM_OR_FINAR_DESC.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CHARGES_DETAIL>
  <IRBILGS_CD_AMT.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CHARGES_DETAIL>$2.17</IRBILGS_CD_AMT.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CHARGES_DETAIL>
</Elec_Dtl_b>
<Elec_Dtl_b>
  <IRBILGS_CD_COM_OR_FINAR_DESC.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CHARGES_DETAIL>Generation of electricity*</IRBILGS_CD_COM_OR_FINAR_DESC.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CHARGES_DETAIL>
  <IRBILGS_CD_AMT.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CHARGES_DETAIL>$18.23</IRBILGS_CD_AMT.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CHARGES_DETAIL>
</Elec_Dtl_b>
<Elec_Dtl_b>
  <IRBILGS_CD_COM_OR_FINAR_DESC.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CHARGES_DETAIL>Federal transmission and ancillary services*</IRBILGS_CD_COM_OR_FINAR_DESC.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CHARGES_DETAIL>
  <IRBILGS_CD_AMT.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CHARGES_DETAIL>$1.61</IRBILGS_CD_AMT.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CHARGES_DETAIL>
</Elec_Dtl_b>
<Elec_Dtl_b>
  <IRBILGS_CD_COM_OR_FINAR_DESC.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CHARGES_DETAIL>Federal transmission cost adjustment*</IRBILGS_CD_COM_OR_FINAR_DESC.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CHARGES_DETAIL>
  <IRBILGS_CD_AMT.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CHARGES_DETAIL>$2.16</IRBILGS_CD_AMT.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CHARGES_DETAIL>
</Elec_Dtl_b>
<Elec_Dtl_b>
  <IRBILGS_CD_COM_OR_FINAR_DESC.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CHARGES_DETAIL>Four-Corners adjustment*</IRBILGS_CD_COM_OR_FINAR_DESC.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CHARGES_DETAIL>
  <IRBILGS_CD_AMT.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CHARGES_DETAIL>$0.77</IRBILGS_CD_AMT.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CHARGES_DETAIL>
</Elec_Dtl_b>
<Elec_Dtl_b>
  <IRBILGS_CD_COM_OR_FINAR_DESC.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CHARGES_DETAIL>LFCR adjustor</IRBILGS_CD_COM_OR_FINAR_DESC.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CHARGES_DETAIL>
  <IRBILGS_CD_AMT.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CHARGES_DETAIL>$0.66</IRBILGS_CD_AMT.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CHARGES_DETAIL>
</Elec_Dtl_b>
```

This is what I attempted. I used the Union extension and then tried to merge the amount values and keep the name the same. When I debug it returns `charge = count = 0` when it should have at 21. the ** is where i made the change

```
private static ServiceAddressBillDetail GetServiceAccountUsageAndBillingDetail(string requestSA, string xmlBill, XmlNodeList detailPageNodes)
{
    var saBillDetail = new ServiceAddressBillDetail();
    saBillDetail.UsageServiceName = requestSA;

    foreach (XmlNode detailPageNode in detailPageNodes)
    {
        if (saBillDetail.Charges == null)
        {
            saBillDetail.Charges = new List<Charge>();
        }
        ***saBillDetail.Charges.Union(XmlBillParser.GetChargeList(detailPageNode));

        ***saBillDetail.Charges = saBillDetail.Charges.GroupBy(p => p.Name).Select(p => new Charge { Name = p.First().Name, Amount = p.Sum(v => v.Amount.Replace("$", "").ConvertToDecimal()).Value.ToString("C") }).ToList();
    }
}
```

Can you guys tell me why this isn't working and how I can actually do it? I am beginner programmer and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: have you stepped through the code..? also are you reading from an existing XML file and if so .. have you tried loading the xml into a datatable and viewing it that way as well as Iterating / checking values..

Comment: I don't think `Union` does what you think it does.  I think you want `Concat`.  These LINQ functions *do not change* your existing list, so you need to work with the return value from `Concat`.

Comment: @CharlesMager I tried `Concat` but that still returns 0. any other suggestions?

Comment: Step through it with a debugger.  Are there any in `Charges`?  Does `GetChargeList` return anything?  Other than that, you'd need to provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem.  Your issue has nothing really to do with XML or most of the code you've included.

Comment: @CharlesMager yes chargeList in GetChargeList returns a count of 22. but when it returns that into `saBillDetail.Charges.Union(XmlBillParser.GetChargeList(detailPageNode));` then `saBillDetail.Charges` has a count of 0. sorry im still learning the ropes

Comment: [`Union`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb341731(v=vs.100).aspx) doesn't join them together, it's a set based operation that returns the items that exist in both sequences.  You want [`Concat`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb302894(v=vs.100).aspx), which joins two sequences together.  You *need to use the result* of that as *it has no side effects*.  i.e. `var charges = x.Concat(y)` and use `charges.GroupBy(....`.

Comment: @CharlesMager I was able to use AddRange to solve my issue